# Google cloud run and web scraping with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am currently trying to get a web scraping script to be used on Google Cloud to import data to the Google Sheets API. I had a quick look around and Google Cloud Run seems that it may be able to do this. Unfortunately the script requires Selenium and headless browsing to run the script and I'm coming up short on how to do this properly. I am quite new to the idea of serverless scripts and can't seem to find much out on the web that's specific enough to my needs with regards to Selenium.

I have been able to Dockerize the script/dependencies with Selenium with headless Chrome. However I'm wondering what may be the best way to deploy this in Google Cloud ?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp for an in-depth example of how to use Headless Chrome + Selenium on Cloud Run.

Comment: Hi Dustin! Thanks for the info! Can I ask why it is necessary to use flask and gunicorn to get it running in gcloud ?

Comment: It's not, they're just our recommended web framework and HTTP server for Python.